# Enable the "show snap layouts when I drag a window to the top of my screen" option?

Tags: windows, windows-11

I can't find this option on my installation of Windows 11 with the latest updates.

There should be an option under System - Multi Tasking that says, "show snap layouts when I drag a window to the top of my screen". But I don't have that option.

[image: Option Not Found]

If I have a look at another PC I have with Windows 11 with latest updates I have these options.

[image: With Options Found]

I have tried registry hacks and changes that I have found online but they don't work.

```
    Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; Created by: Shawn Brink
; Created on: April 28, 2022
; Tutorial: https://www.elevenforum.com/t/enable-or-disable-snap-layouts-on-top-of-screen-in-windows-11.6142/


[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]
"WindowArrangementActive"="1"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]
"EnableSnapBar"=dword:00000001
```

Anybody know how I can enable this feature on my Windows 11.

Comment: I am on 11 23H2 and do not see what you are looking for.  Did you try Title bar Shake?   I do not know if that offers what you need.

Comment: Have you not seen this before? https://pureinfotech.com/disable-drag-top-screen-snap-layouts-windows-11/

Comment: I read the article . That is an older version of Windows 11 than I have here.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. I was on an older version of windows 11 and had to do a manual update. I think because my CPU isn't officially supported by windows 11. After the in place upgrade to 23H2 it now works.